# como transformar de string a Color android

Tags: android, kotlin, composer, jetpack-compose

Necesito transformar de un string a la propiedad Color
tengo una api que me da la siguiente respuesta `"mainColor": "#8439FF",` esta es la respuesta que necesito transformar a  Color

ya eh probado lo siguiente

```
int color = Color.parseColor(mainColor);

val string = mainColor
val ColorPrimario = string.replaceFirst("^#".toRegex(), "").toInt(16)
```

el problema con estas soluciones es que me lo pasa de string a int, pero la propiedad que necesito es color. por que de otra forma me marca error

Comment: Estás en [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada.

Comment: Intentaste `Color.parseColor("#8439FF")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el valor Int del color a partir del còdigo RGB simplemente, usa el mètodo [parseColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)):

> [parseColor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color#parseColor(java.lang.String)) Analize la cadena de color y devuelva el color-int
> correspondiente.

No tienes que eliminar el simbolo `#`, este es necesario, ejemplo:

```
val mainColor = "#8439FF"
int color = Color.parseColor(mainColor)
```